# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/data/ca.srl'

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose

I am trying to install this [Github Repo](https://github.com/chuot/rdio-scanner) using the [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/chuot/rdio-scanner). I am following [these instructions](https://github.com/chuot/rdio-scanner/blob/master/docs/install-docker.md) and I am getting this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/data/ca.srl'
    at Object.statSync (fs.js:1127:3)
    at internal/fs/utils.js:709:32
    at hidden (internal/errors.js:294:14)
    at Object.rmSync (fs.js:931:13)
    at new <anonymous> (/app/server/index.js:1:71639)
    at /app/server/index.js:1:69383
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/index.js:1:73817)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'stat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/app/data/ca.srl'
}
```

However, when I install this using the [docker-compose](https://github.com/chuot/rdio-scanner/blob/master/docs/examples/rdio-scanner/docker-compose.yml) file or the [Github repo code](https://github.com/chuot/rdio-scanner/blob/master/docs/install-github.md), it works perfectly fine.

I am learning docker and trying to figure out why I get this error and how can I fix this.

I am using WSL2, Ubuntu 18.0 LTS on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason might be, when you executed the `docker run`, the file or directory was not mounted correctly to `/app/data` in the container. The path mapping is different from the settings in the docker compose yml file. Check this for further information: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag

Comment: This is the command I am using: `docker run --detach --env TZ=America/Toronto --name rdio-scanner --publish 3000:3000 --restart always --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --volume ~/.rdio-scanner:/app/data chuot/rdio-scanner:latest`, but it still not mounting.